# Add equation in multirow (tabular)

Tags: tables, equations, multirow

I would like to add an equation in a multirow cell, using tabular and a defined width.
It worked everywhere in the table, except for a cell which is a multirow of two other multirows. In this case, I get an error. (The cell is indicated as HERE in the attached picture). Do you have any idea how to solve it? Thank you! [image]

```
    \RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions} 
  \documentclass{DissOnlineLatex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools, eqparbox}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\newcommand{\eqbox}[2][]{\eqmakebox[#1][l]{\mbox{#2~}}}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.4\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{V}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.65\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=0.2\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\hsize=1.0\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{d}{>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{SIunits}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[   
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    sortcites,   
    sorting = anyvt,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    backref,
    natbib,
    hyperref
  ]{biblatex}
  \begin{document}
  
\begin{table}[htb]
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
    \caption{Necessary liquid-gas ratios for concave and convex equilibrium lines.}
    \label{table:Nec_LG}
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|M{4.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|M{3.0cm}|M{4.0cm}|}        
        \hline
        \textbf{LG} & \textbf{Description} &\textbf{Goal} & {\textbf{Case}} & {\textbf{LG=}}\\
        \hline
        \hline
        \multirow{2}[4]{*}{$LG_a$} & \multirow{2}[4]{=}{Minimal LG for maximal (de)humidification} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{$\omega_t=\omega_t^*$} & Convex & \begin{equation}
        \frac{\partial \omega^*}{\partial \xi}\Bigr\rvert_{\xi = \xi_t}
        \label{eq:ratio_a_pinch_convex}
        \end{equation} \\
        \cline{4-5}          &       &       & Concave & \multirow{2}{*}{
            HERE
        } \\
        \cline{1-4}    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{$LG_d$} & \multirow{2}[4]{=}{Maximal LG for maximal dilution or regeneration} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{$\xi_b=\xi_b^*$} & Concave &  \\
        \cline{4-5}          &       &       & Convex & \begin{equation}
        \frac{\partial \omega^*}{\partial \xi}\Bigr\rvert_{\xi = \xi_b^*} 
        \label{eq:ratio_d_pinch_convex} \end{equation} \\
        \hline
        \hline          
        \multirow{4}{*}{$LG_h$} & \multirow{4}{=}{Minimal LG for specified (de)-humidification} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\omega_t=\omega_{t,goal}$}& Straight, concave and convex $LG_h\le LG_d$& \begin{equation}
        \frac{\omega_b-\omega_{t,goal}}{\xi_b^*-\xi_t}
        \label{eq:ratio_h_pinch_concave}
        \end{equation}\\        
        \cline{4-5}
        &  &  & convex $LG_h\ge LG_d$ & \begin{equation}
        \frac{\omega^*(\hat{\xi})-\omega_{t,goal}}{\hat{\xi}-\xi_t}
        \label{eq:ratio_h_pinch_convex}
        \end{equation} \\
        \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{$LG_r$} & \multirow{4}{=}{Maximal LG for specified  dilution or regeneration} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\xi_b=\xi_{b,goal}$}& Straight, concave and convex $LG_r\ge LG_a$& \begin{equation}
        \frac{\omega_b-\omega_t^*}{\xi_{b,goal}-\xi_t}
        \label{eq:ratio_r_pinch_concave}
        \end{equation}\\        
        \cline{4-5}
        &  &  & convex $LG_r<LG_a$ & \begin{equation}
        \frac{\omega_{b}-\omega^*(\hat{\xi})}{\xi_{b,goal}-\hat{\xi}}
        \label{eq:ratio_r_pinch_convex}
        \end{equation} \\
        \hline      
        \hline      
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Umm, is the `DissOnlineLatex` document class available online somewhere?

Comment: Incidentally, what's the purpose of running `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` if you're not going to use a `tabularx` column?

Comment: Thanks Miko for trying.
I forgot to upload DissOnlineLatex. But the file works with article anyway.
I just used this \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} for other tables I have in may document.
Next time I'll try to prepare the code better.
A possible solution has already been posted by Andrew.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the `DissOnlineLatex` document class so I have used article in what follows.

I would not put `equation` environments inside a `tabular` environment and I would have thought that this would lead to a pile of errors. So, I am surprised that you only get one error inside the `\multirow` cells. I guess that this works because you are using an `M`-column type. If you want to put an `equation` environment inside the `\multirow` cell then the obvious thing to do is to put the `equation` inside a `minipage` environment. Using this seems to do what you want:

[image]

Setting the width of the `minipage` environment to `\linbewidth` should, in theory, give the correct width. I found by trial and error that using `0.97\linewidth` worked better in that this made the equation number in this cell align properly with the other equation numbers. Here is your modified MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools, eqparbox}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\newcommand{\eqbox}[2][]{\eqmakebox[#1][l]{\mbox{#2~}}}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.4\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{V}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.65\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=0.2\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\hsize=1.0\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{d}{>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{SIunits}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    sortcites,
    sorting = anyvt,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    backref,
    natbib,
    hyperref
  ]{biblatex}
  \begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
    \caption{Necessary liquid-gas ratios for concave and convex equilibrium lines.}
    \label{table:Nec_LG}
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|M{4.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|M{3.0cm}|M{4.0cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{LG} & \textbf{Description} &\textbf{Goal} & {\textbf{Case}} & {\textbf{LG=}}\\
        \hline
        \hline
        \multirow{2}[4]{*}{$LG_a$} & \multirow{2}[4]{=}{Minimal LG for maximal (de)humidification} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{$\omega_t=\omega_t^*$} & Convex & \begin{equation}
        \frac{\partial \omega^*}{\partial \xi}\Bigr\rvert_{\xi = \xi_t}
        \label{eq:ratio_a_pinch_convex}
        \end{equation} \\
        \cline{4-5}          &       &       & Concave & \multirow{2}{*}{
        \begin{minipage}{0.97\linewidth}
        \begin{equation}\label{E:}
\frac{\partial \omega^*}{\partial \xi}\Bigr\rvert_{\xi = \xi_b^*}
        \end{equation}
        \end{minipage}
        } \\
        \cline{1-4}    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{$LG_d$} & \multirow{2}[4]{=}{Maximal LG for maximal dilution or regeneration} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{$\xi_b=\xi_b^*$} & Concave &  \\
        \cline{4-5}          &       &       & Convex & \begin{equation}
        \frac{\partial \omega^*}{\partial \xi}\Bigr\rvert_{\xi = \xi_b^*}
        \label{eq:ratio_d_pinch_convex} \end{equation} \\
        \hline
        \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{$LG_h$} & \multirow{4}{=}{Minimal LG for specified (de)-humidification} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\omega_t=\omega_{t,goal}$}& Straight, concave and convex $LG_h\le LG_d$& \begin{equation}
        \frac{\omega_b-\omega_{t,goal}}{\xi_b^*-\xi_t}
        \label{eq:ratio_h_pinch_concave}
        \end{equation}\\
        \cline{4-5}
        &  &  & convex $LG_h\ge LG_d$ & \begin{equation}
        \frac{\omega^*(\hat{\xi})-\omega_{t,goal}}{\hat{\xi}-\xi_t}
        \label{eq:ratio_h_pinch_convex}
        \end{equation} \\
        \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{$LG_r$} & \multirow{4}{=}{Maximal LG for specified  dilution or regeneration} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\xi_b=\xi_{b,goal}$}& Straight, concave and convex $LG_r\ge LG_a$& \begin{equation}
        \frac{\omega_b-\omega_t^*}{\xi_{b,goal}-\xi_t}
        \label{eq:ratio_r_pinch_concave}
        \end{equation}\\
        \cline{4-5}
        &  &  & convex $LG_r<LG_a$ & \begin{equation}
        \frac{\omega_{b}-\omega^*(\hat{\xi})}{\xi_{b,goal}-\hat{\xi}}
        \label{eq:ratio_r_pinch_convex}
        \end{equation} \\
        \hline
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow Andrew, this is great. Thanks a lot for your help!
I didn't know that it is recommended not to use equations insede tabular (although I managed it after trying a lot of different things). So your way is much simpler and works perfectly. Thanks again :)